# In React Native Library How Can I get ios current UIViewController

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

react native library in android can use "getCurrentActivity()" to replace "this"

```
final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
```

And In ios How can use to replace "self" to get current UIViewController

Comment: Hi @kiel. Have you fixed this instead of using rootViewController.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in iOS. But i don't want to set the rootViewController. becase when i click back to moves to root view itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS - unless you use wix's react native navigation - there is generally only one `UIViewController`, instantiated in your AppDelegate.

1st question: Why do you need your app UIViewController ?

if you really need to access it, here is a suggestion : `UIApplication.sharedApplication().window.rootViewController` (this code might not work for complex native setup, but for simple cases, it should give you your app ViewController)

Comment: Because I have a function will popup a view and i need to pass my current view.
In android i pass getActivity() is work 
but in ios i pass "self" is return error 
(Could not cast value of type MyLibrary to 'UIViewController'.)

Answer (score 8):

For "current UIViewController" you most probably needs `RCTPresentedViewController` function from `RCTUtils.h` file:

```objc
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>

// ...
  UIViewController* vc = RCTPresentedViewController();
// ...
```

Note: Very old RN versions do not has this API, but it can be easy implemented by hands, implementation is easy enough: [RCTUtils.m](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.59-stable/React/Base/RCTUtils.m#L492-L506)